# 500 when calling setTitle using angular 2 titleService and server side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-services

I have a problem with server side rendering using angular 2 and titleService.

My code looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [Title]
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private titleService: Title) {
        titleService.setTitle("Setting the title...");
    }
}
```

This works fine using client side rendering but when reloading the page I get this error:

*Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot create property 'title' on string ''*

Any ideas why this occurs?

Comment: which line of code throws that error?

Comment: Post your service

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Title service is a built-in Angular service

Comment: Maybe it is similar to this one, and you could use `JSON.parse`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445517/cannot-create-property-type-on-string-radio-button-filters

Comment: Are you using any external libraries like angular-universal?

Comment: @echonax, yes i am using angular-universal.

this is more of the stacktrace:

at Parse5DomAdapter.module.exports.Parse5DomAdapter.setTitle (<Path>\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:91706:89)
at Title.setTitle (<Path>\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:25594:67)
at new AppComponent (<Path>\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:288:22)

Comment: @martenolofsson have you checked https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12431, https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/406 ?

Comment: @echonax I guess this might be expected since the titleService interacts with element only present in the browser. When reading the "Universal Gotchas" it clearly status that you need to check if you are on the client or in the browser when doing this. I expected the titleService to handle such things though. However checking if client solved the problem.

Comment: @martenolofsson ah glad you figured it out. You can self-answer your question and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might be expected since the titleService interacts with element only present in the browser. When reading the "Universal Gotchas" it clearly status that you need to check if you are on the client or in the browser when doing this. I expected the titleService to handle such things though. However checking if client solved the problem.

Se: https://github.com/angular/universal

Answer (score 1):

With angular universal there should be no need to provide any external service as this is built in. (as [echonax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5706293/echonax) stated in the comments.)

Working example with this [angular-universal fork](https://github.com/evertonrobertoauler/cli-universal-demo). I guess it should be the same for your version of angular-universal.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _meta: Meta, private _title: Title) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {      
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        switch (event.urlAfterRedirects) {
          case '/':
            this._title.setTitle('title goes here');
            this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'same goes for meta content' });
            break;
          case '/another-route':
            this._title.setTitle('Another title');
            this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'You get the idea' });
            break;

        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

NavigationEnd takes care of setting a new title each time I navigate to a new route.

Hope it helps.